# using getElementById to get input from a multiline text file into id

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a novice at javascript and I'm trying to collect and display information from a text file for manipulation.  It is for a caption that needs to be displayed when the program starts up.

So far, I can get the function to work for one line, but when I tried using it for multiple lines, it only grabs the first line of text from the text file and displays it as many times I call it.

### I know I need to maybe use an array, but that's a bit more advanced than where I'm currently at.  Please let me know if using an array is the most efficient or only way to do this.  The sample code is below, and I'm not married to my idea.  I'm just trying to figure out the best way to make it work.  My group has a template maker, but I can always change they way to do this if it is better.

function write_caption_view(){

```
var fsow;
fsow = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

text_write = fsow.OpenTextFile(" ", 2, true, -2);       
text_write.writeline(document.getElementById("cap").value);

text_write.Close();

stat_write = fsow.OpenTextFile(" ", 2, true, -2);
stat_write.writeline("CONFIGURED");
stat_write.close(); 

alert("Saved Caption");
```

}

function read_caption_view(){

```
var fsor;
fsor = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
text_read = fsor.OpenTextFile(" ", 1, false, -2);
caption_notice = text_read.readline();
text_read.Close();

document.getElementById('cap').value = caption_notice;
```

}
function display_caption_view(){

```
document.getElementById('cap').innerHTML = caption_notice;
```

### }

Comment: We cannot know what your array is unless you post an example of the array or the contents of the file.

Comment: Thanks, the content of the file is just a simply text message.  It is approximately 12 lines in the text message, and I'm trying to avoid having 12-15 txt files to pull the text individually and then display them.  I'm not currently using an array, and that's what I'm trying to determine if it is needed.  I've heard it is a challenge to work with arrays, and as I noted, I'm a basic user who trying to learn as I go.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice [example](https://codepen.io/franciskim/pen/eNjrpR) that shows how to split a multiline string into arrays

Basically, you have to split the string by newline

```
var lines = $('#input').val().split('\n');
```

or in your case

```
var lines = document.getElementById("cap1").value.split('\n');
```

Now in `lines` you have an array of strings. Those can be processed further with an iterator.

Please notice [a simpler way](https://davidwalsh.name/multiline-javascript-strings) to define a multiple line string in javascript is:

```
var multiStr = "This is the first line \
    This is the second line \
    This is more...";
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to work on this.  I have about 6 or 7 more multiline strings text files on different function sets, so figuring this out will save a ton of scripting.  Trying to work smarter, not harder PLUS this helps in simplifying the code for debugging.

Comment: You can iterate the elements and compose the name like "cap" + index

Comment: I probably should have included the read function as well.  The program initially read an input from the text file, and the user can then modify if they want or change it.  I'm testing it without worrying about the read function to get a better understanding of this, but I might need to just set-up separate text files for each line.  Thanks again.:

Comment: ```lang-js
function read_caption_view(){

 var fsor;
 fsor = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
 text_read = fsor.OpenTextFile(drive_root+"/configurations/caption_notice.txt", 1, false, -2);
 caption_notice = text_read.readline();
 text_read.Close();
 
 document.getElementById('cap1').value = caption_notice;
 document.getElementById('cap2').value = caption_notice;
 document.getElementById('cap3').value = caption_notice;```

Comment: Please add this info in the original question. I think is not all

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the assistance.  I figured out a way to do so without an array, and while not as elegant, it works and provides a version that easy to update.

function write_caption_view(){

```
var fsow, fsor;
fsor = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
fsow = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

text_write = fsow.OpenTextFile("file location", 2, true, -2);       
text_write.writeline(document.getElementById("capline1").value);
text_write.writeline(document.getElementById("capline2").value);
text_write.writeline(document.getElementById("capline3").value);
text_write.writeline(document.getElementById("capline4").value);
text_write.writeline(document.getElementById("capline5").value);
text_write.writeline(document.getElementById("capline6").value);
text_write.writeline(document.getElementById("capline7").value);
text_write.writeline(document.getElementById("capline8").value);
text_write.writeline(document.getElementById("capline9").value);
text_write.writeline(document.getElementById("capline10").value);
text_write.writeline(document.getElementById("capline11").value);
text_write.writeline(document.getElementById("capline12").value);
text_write.writeline(document.getElementById("capline13").value);
text_write.writeline(document.getElementById("capline14").value);
text_write.writeline(document.getElementById("capline15").value);

text_write.Close();

stat_write = fsow.OpenTextFile("file location", 2, true, -2);
stat_write.writeline("CONFIGURED");
stat_write.close(); 

alert("Saved Caption");
```

}

function read_caption_view(){

```
var fsor;
fsor = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

fsor = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
text_read = fsor.OpenTextFile("file location", 1, false, -2);
caption_notice_line1 = text_read.readline();
caption_notice_line2 = text_read.readline();
caption_notice_line3 = text_read.readline();
caption_notice_line4 = text_read.readline();
caption_notice_line5 = text_read.readline();
caption_notice_line6 = text_read.readline();
caption_notice_line7 = text_read.readline();
caption_notice_line8 = text_read.readline();
caption_notice_line9 = text_read.readline();
caption_notice_line10 = text_read.readline();
caption_notice_line11 = text_read.readline();
caption_notice_line12 = text_read.readline();
caption_notice_line13 = text_read.readline();
caption_notice_line14 = text_read.readline();
caption_notice_line15 = text_read.readline();

text_read.Close();

document.getElementById('capline1').innerHTML = caption_notice_line1;
document.getElementById('capline2').innerHTML = caption_notice_line2;
document.getElementById('capline3').innerHTML = caption_notice_line3;
document.getElementById('capline4').innerHTML = caption_notice_line4;
document.getElementById('capline5').innerHTML = caption_notice_line5;
document.getElementById('capline6').innerHTML = caption_notice_line6;
document.getElementById('capline7').innerHTML = caption_notice_line7;
document.getElementById('capline8').innerHTML = caption_notice_line8;
document.getElementById('capline9').innerHTML = caption_notice_line9;
document.getElementById('capline10').innerHTML = caption_notice_line10;
document.getElementById('capline11').innerHTML = caption_notice_line11;
document.getElementById('capline12').innerHTML = caption_notice_line12;
document.getElementById('capline13').innerHTML = caption_notice_line13;
document.getElementById('capline14').innerHTML = caption_notice_line14;
document.getElementById('capline15').innerHTML = caption_notice_line15;
```

}

function display_caption_view(){

```
document.getElementById('capline1').innerHTML = caption_notice_line1;
document.getElementById('capline2').innerHTML = caption_notice_line2;
document.getElementById('capline3').innerHTML = caption_notice_line3;
document.getElementById('capline4').innerHTML = caption_notice_line4;
document.getElementById('capline5').innerHTML = caption_notice_line5;
document.getElementById('capline6').innerHTML = caption_notice_line6;
document.getElementById('capline7').innerHTML = caption_notice_line7;
document.getElementById('capline8').innerHTML = caption_notice_line8;
document.getElementById('capline9').innerHTML = caption_notice_line9;
document.getElementById('capline10').innerHTML = caption_notice_line10;
document.getElementById('capline11').innerHTML = caption_notice_line11;
document.getElementById('capline12').innerHTML = caption_notice_line12;
document.getElementById('capline13').innerHTML = caption_notice_line13;
document.getElementById('capline14').innerHTML = caption_notice_line14;
document.getElementById('capline15').innerHTML = caption_notice_line15;
```

}